# Insert multiple checkbox values in MysQl

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following checkbox items and I want to insert them in the database.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="rice:10">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="milk:8">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="orange:4">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The following is the php code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) { 
        $mealA = explode(":",$check);
        $meal = $mealA[0];
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Order (User, Meal, Total) VALUES ('$name' , '$meal', '$total')";
        if (mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql1)) {
            echo "You order has been recieved";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql1;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the value of each checkbox means item name:price.

The problem is that I got error `"Error: " . $sql1;`

Comment: Where is `$mysqli` value coming from ?

Comment: Also, try adding `mysqli_error` to your code: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Change `"Error: " . $sql1` to `"Error:" . mysqli_error($mysqli)` so you can have a better understanding of why it fails.

Comment: echo the three values $name, $meal, and $total to see what exactly is contained in them. If they look fine try running the failing sql command manually in mysql to see if it still gives an error.

Comment: I changed what @kidA suggested and got this error `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (User, Meal, Total) VALUES ('bero' , 'margherita', )' at line 1Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (User, Meal, Total) VALUES ('bero' , 'sicilian', )' at line 1`

Answer (score 2):

Your query fails because you have not set a value for `$total`. So either you have to remove the `Total` field from the query resulting in

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO Order (User, Meal) VALUES ('$name' , '$meal')";
```

which will give a `NULL` value to the `Total` column for each successful new insert

**OR**

based on the code you provided I 'm guessing you wanted to do something similar to this?

```
$mealA = explode(":",$check);
$meal = $mealA[0];
$total = $mealA[1]; // setting the value of $total otherwise query is going to fail
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO Order (User, Meal, Total) VALUES ('$name' , '$meal', '$total')";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Order (User, Meal, Total) VALUES ('$name' , '$meal', '$total')
```

I changed the table name from `Order` to `Orders` and I removed `Total` since it is null and there is no value stored in it.

Thanks for your suggestions.